# Insert new rows and populate

Tags: vba, excel

I need help creating a excel macro to split orders based on qty column.
In the before sheet we have 4 orders with two of them having a qty greater the 1. see before macro image

What I need is an excel macro that can check the qty field and insert new rows below based on qty value if greater then 1, then populate these rows with the data from the original row. 
Then the last step would be to delete the C column. See After Macro image

I have never used macros before, so i'm not even sure if this can be done.

[image: Before Marco]
[image: After Macro]

Comment: It can be done with vba, but SO is not a "code for me site".  Look into iterating or looping through cells, inserting rows, copying or filling down and deleting column.

Answer (score -2):

It's only 10 lines of code. SO is not a code sweatshop where we do the work for you, it is one where we help you work it out for yourself.

This will poll the rows for you going backwards:

```
For X = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
```

This is key because you will be inserting rows, going forwards creates all sort of nastiness.

You will then need a loop inside there using your qty as a reference. Here is one I built but you will need to make some changes for it to work for your columns:

```
For Y = 1 To Range("B" & X).Value - 1
```

Then you need to copy row X inside this loop

Next line will be an insert with a shift down (like this `Insert Shift:=xlDown`) on row X + 1 or on an offset of row X by 1 row, your choice how you do this.

Last thing to do is delete column C, This can be done like this `Range("C1").EntireColumn.Delete`

That is it, the whole macro, just drop a couple of nexts and an end sub and run it.

You will need to Dim X and Y, dim them as longs.

Have a go, if you get stuck post back with the code you have put together and we can help you fix it.